Text based wallet use with on mainnet
I have this problem where my solana text wallet made on ubuntu is on devnet. I want to use this wallet for mainnet uses like sending sols or something like that. Is there a way or code snippet that would allow me to do this?
Thanks in advance!

I think by "solana text wallet made on ubuntu", you mean the paper wallet create via solana CLI. You can change the RPC URL to mainnet via solana config set -um command
